# Iterate over queried dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I'm trying to iterate over a queried Pandas dataframe: Column=ORIG_FID. So for every ORIG_FID (0, 1,2,...) I have **two rows** of (x,y).
[image]

Then I would like to use ax.plot(x,y) drawing a line that joins every pair of coordinates for every ORIG_FID.

So far I've tried this:

```
for i in df[df['ORIG_FID'].eq(i)]:
    ax.plot(df[df['x']].values.tolist()[i], df[df['y']].values.tolist()[i])
```

Note: Also, there is one particular dataframe that doesn't have two rows per ORIG_FID (it can have 2, 3 or whatever number of rows) but the idea is the same, I'd like to plot straight lines for every coordinate in every ORIG_FID value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output data according to [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) to make a [mcve]

Comment: there is something wrong in this line "for i in df[df['ORIG_FID'].eq(i)]:"
"i" is repeated in the statement of the for loop

Comment: Check sample input image. Expected output data: ax.plot(x, y) for (x,y)-pair in every ORIG_FID.